# I want to know if django can dynamically add html tags, just like javascrip

Tags: django

I want to know if django can dynamically add html tags, just like javascrip.if so, how to add html tags dynamically with django-template

Answer (score 0):

the html generated by Django can be dynamic in the sense it has the template logic applied at the server, however, once generated and delivered to the browser Django cannot change the html. Using Javascript you can modify the html at the client.